# Closing Google v3 API InfoWindow, using FusionTables Layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, google-fusion-tables

We are generating a map with Markers/Infowindows via FusionTables.

The map is being presented via a FusionTables Layer, and I am using the [InfoBox plugin](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) in order to create my own custom style of InfoWindow.

This is all fine and dandy. My window appears as I expected.

However, since I'm using our FusionTables setup, all the Markers/InfoWindows are generated. At no point have I manually declared them.

Because of this, I'm getting two InfoWindows. The google default, and my new InfoBox version. I'm creating the Infobox through this listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
    var text = e.infoWindowHtml;
    infoBox.setContent(text);
    infoBox.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infoBox.open(map);
});
```

At this point, the e results in the following when I log it:

```
Object
    infoWindowHtml: "My Code Is In Here"
    latLng: P
    pixelOffset: U
    row: Object
    __proto__: Object
```

I'm looking for a method to prevent the original InfoWindow from displaying. At the very least, a method to hide/close the InfoWindow on InfoBox open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like google updated the API docs today
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#FusionTablesLayerOptions

Setting suppressInfoWindows to true will stop the built in info windows from appearing.

Comment: Awesome find, would seek advice from again, A+++++